# Applying a skinid to a label using themes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to apply a skin on runtime to a label using a skinid i created from a skin file. The theme folder is called skin1. The SkinID is called Error. When I try to Apply the Skin1 theme folder thru the Page_PreInt Method to the label using the skinid, Nothing seems to happen.

Code:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Mytheme"] = "Skin1";
        lblMessage.SkinID = Session["Mytheme"].ToString();
    }
```

The Label in the Hmtl:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" SkinID="Error"  Text="HELLO WORLD">
</asp:Label>
```

The Skin file in the theme folder:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" SkinID="Error" ForeColor="Red"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skin just this one control you need to apply the theme, but turn it off at the page level and on at for the controls you wish to skin. E.g.

```
<%@ Page Theme="skin1" EnableTheming="false" %>
```

And then setting the skin id should be sufficient:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" SkinID="Error" Text="HELLO WORLD" EnableTheming="true">
</asp:Label>
```

Or programmatically:

```
Page.EnableTheming = false;
Page.Theme = "skin1";
lblMessage.SkinID = "Error";
lblMessage.EnableTheming = true;
```

Comment: I know that way works   at design time, but I was trying to get it to work at runtime, by using the Page_PreInit Method. I know I can also assign Page.Theme = "Skin1"; to the Page_PreInit and it will also do the job, But I was trying to get it work with just a label, not the entire page.

Comment: Ah okay, try this instead

Comment: Page.EnableTheming = false; is giving me an error. 'System.InvalidOperationException' The 'EnableTheming' property can only be set in or before the Page_PreInit event for static controls.

Comment: Thanks. Codemonkeh. It worked. But I had to set the EnableTheming attribute in the page directive on my web form first, before i tried to use the page.theme and skinID  programmatically in the code behind the file. My debugger wouldn't allow me to place the Page.EnableTheming in the Page_PreInit method.